Find out resources being contested by futex system call
Trying to profile an application on SuSE Linux 15 with following command:
strace -f -s 512 -o /tmp/strace_dump.out -v -tt -T -C -yy -q <my_application>

Observed that 90% of the application runtime is being spent on futex system call.
This is quite big as my application has been suffering from slowness and long runtimes.
How do I proceed from this point onwards?
Below are example futex entries I observed in my dump file:
20680 09:36:35.012339 futex(0x7ffff6c787c8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0 <0.000008>
.
.
22580 09:36:36.023194 futex(0x7ffff7e0f028, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>

And many more. What is interesting is that there are about 1.25 million futex calls and about 600K of these are failing.
What can I do here to improve my application performance? I do not have access to the source code as of now.

as you've not shared any code / context any replies are going to be speculative, sharing code , give context would help .

"What can I do here to improve my application performance? I do not have access to the source code as of now." - well then you cannot really do anything... The first step would be to look at the source, profile and debug the code. The second one would be to figure out how futex contention could be reduced and test it. All things that require access to the source code.
